# Nginx + Passenger возможно ли перезагрузить конкретный инстанс?

Tags: nginx, ruby, linux

Возможно ли перезагрузить (чтобы загрузились изменения) один из настроенных серверов на базе passenger, не перезагружая весь nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что невозможно. Почитайте здесь:

[Phusion Passenger users guide, Nginx version | modrails.com](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html)

Comment: By creating or modifying the file tmp/restart.txt in the Rails application’s root folder. Phusion Passenger will automatically restart the application during the next request.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin, оформите ответ правильно пожалуйста, чтобы я мог его принять.

Comment: Чад, дело в том, что я с nginx + passenger вообще ни разу не работал, а знал только теоретически. Я просто сделал за вас работу по поиску доки, в которой вы и нашли ответ.  А теперь насчёт оформления. Что я там должен поправить?

Comment: Напишите что для перегрузки конкретного app для nginx надо модифицировать файл tmp/restart.txt

Comment: А зачем? Мне мой статус пофиг, это я вам хотел помочь, и доку подогнал! А лично мне ничего тут не неадо!

Comment: @Anton  Reshin, Ну, это сеть знаний вообще-то. Чем она стройнее, тем мир лучше.